# Fields involving NaN

Tags: abstract-algebra

## Motivation

NaN as a value exists in IEEE floating-point numbers. Since every operation involving NaN has NaN as the outcome, IEEE floating-point numbers are not fields. I want to define a new algebraic structure so NaN could be encapsulated.

## Definitions

A field $(F,+,\times)$ is **NaNable** if there exists a binary operation $\sim$ such that $(F \cup \{\text{NaN}\}, \sim, +)$ is a field, where $\text{NaN}$ is the identity element of $\sim$.

$(F \cup \{\text{NaN}\}, \sim, +,\times)$ is a **NaNification** of $(F,+,\times)$, and is a **NaN-field**.

## Examples

Examples of NaNable finite fields include $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $\mathbb{Z}_7$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{31}$. The operation tables of NaNification of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\sim & \text{NaN} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{NaN} & \text{NaN} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & \text{NaN} & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & \text{NaN} & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & \text{NaN} \\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+ & \text{NaN} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{NaN} & \text{NaN} & \text{NaN} & \text{NaN} & \text{NaN} \\
0 & \text{NaN} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & \text{NaN} & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & \text{NaN} & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

Note that multiplication involving $\text{NaN}$ is not defined yet.

## Questions

1. Is there a notable example of NaNable infinite field?
2. Is there a dedicated name for $\sim$? Not as a symbol, but as an operation?
3. It turns out that if every multiplication involving $\text{NaN}$ is defined as $\text{NaN}$, distributivity is satisfied in the NaN-field. Does this mean I should define it accordingly?

Comment: Any operation involving NaN should (morally) return NaN, so I would say yes to (3). Is there an intuitive interpretation of what $\sim$ should mean?

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarret NaN is some kind of singularity, and $\sim$ just is to compromise the singularity.

Comment: Can you not just define the operations the same way for any finite field (and then presumably for $\mathbb{Z}$ too)?

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett I don't think so.

Comment: The multiplicative group of a field has the property that, for every positive integer $n$, the equation $x^n=1$ has at most $n$ solutions. It follows that a NaNable field, the equation $nx=0$ has at most $n$ solutions. This implies a NaNable field of positive characteristic is a prime field. So if $(F\cup\{NaN\},\sim,+,\times)$ is an infinite NaN field, then $(F,+,\times)$ is characteristic $0$, and it follows that $(F\cup\{NaN\},\sim,+)$ has no non-trivial roots of unity, hence has characteristic $2$.

Comment: @JulianRosen I follow you, but I think $F = \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the only exception on the "characteristic 2" part, where the characteristic is actually 3.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea, but what is the motivation for this $~$ thing, intuitively? Just to make it a field?