# Algebraic Structures involving  (absorbing element).

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, floating-point, monads

IEEE 754 floating point numbers contain the concept of  (not a number), which "dominates" arithmetical operations ($+,-,⋅,÷$ will return  if either argument is ). That is,  is an [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element). However, from an algebraic point of view, FP numbers are very ugly, as they are not even associative.

So instead, consider the following construction: Let $(K, +_{K}, ⋅_{K})$ be any field. Extend $K$ by a singular element $K' ≔ K∪\{\}$, and augment the field operations as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
x +_{K'} y &≔ \begin{cases} :& ∈\{x,y\} \\ x +_{K} y :& \text{else}\end{cases}
&
x ⋅_{K'} y &≔ \begin{cases}\hfill:& ∈\{x,y\}  \\ x ⋅_{K} y\hfill:& \text{else}\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$

The resulting algebraic structure $(K', +_{K'}, ⋅_{K'})$ still satisfies all field axioms except for additive and multiplicative inverses, which fail for the singular distinguished element .

**Question:** Does this algebraic structure have a name? Is it studied in the literature?

The concept seems related to that of the Maybe/Option-Monad, but I am not knowledgeable in category theory.

**Related Questions:**

- [Fields involving NaN](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694866/fields-involving-nan)
- [Algebraic structure for the floating-point arithmetic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445920/algebraic-structure-for-the-floating-point-arithmetic)

Comment: This is related also to wheels.

Comment: This would be a commutative semiring.